# How to make text over image when image have z-index more than text

Tags: css

Here is my problem -

[image]

I have given this CSS to left panel

```
.social {
position: absolute;
top: 16px;
z-index: 1;}
```

And CSS for the project container the CSS is here

```
.projectContainer {
position: relative;
z-index: 10;}
```

I need to give z-index: 10 to .projectContainer because if I give z-index less than .social then links (All, App, Card,..) can not be clickable. Now the project container is coming over the left panel. How I can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: i once made a codepen depending z-index and position context. it might help y reading this: http://codepen.io/paulq/pen/rrOBoQ